# Windows 10 fc command : File comparison

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, comparison, diff

I have two file's with 3 GB each to do a comparison and store the difference data into third file.

Following is the sample data.

**File 1**: June_01_2018.csv

[image]

**File 2**: June_02_2018.csv

[image]

**Note**: I want to store the difference into the third file with the column headers.

**Expected Result**: The third file should contain the records from `ID` 11 to 15 with the column headers.

**My try**: `fc` command in command prompt,

```
>fc June_01_2018.csv June_02_2018.csv > June_Diff.csv
```

But getting unexpected result:

[image]

Comment: What about this: `< "June_01_2018.csv" set HEAD=""` and `> "June_Diff.csv" echo(%HEAD%` and `>>"June_Diff.csv" findstr /V /X /L /G:"June_01_2018.csv" "June_02_2018.csv"`; this should work if the second file contains all data of the first one, like shown in your example...

Comment: @aschipfl, I tried with `findstr` but getting error `FINDSTR: Cannot read strings from file`.

Comment: Strange... what encoding do you use -- ASCII/ANSI? how long are the lines? perhaps you are facing a limitation of `findstr` (too long lines, or too many lines) -- consult this: [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868)

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the header record first, then append the `fc` output.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path 'June_01_2018.csv' | Select-Object -First 1" >June_Diff.csv
fc June_01_2018.csv June_02_2018.csv >> June_Diff.csv
```

Comment: Total records in the first file are 10 millions and second file 11 millions. So there be 1 million more or less records getting appended in latest file. I tried with ‘fc file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt’ but getting error ‘Failed to resych’.

Comment: This sounds like a problem of the `fc` command and not one of getting the header record into the output. The Microsoft answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms827336.aspx Do you have the option of installing another tool?

Comment: Yes I have option.

Comment: A first step might be to install (for free) Cygwin or MinGW and use `diff`, but that might not be the format you like. There is a free `WinDiff`, but I do not know if it can be scripted. If you can purchase a tool, `BeyondCompare` is very strong and has some scripting capability. https://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: Okay will try this.

Comment: [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is a free (GPL) excellent graphical compare (and merge) tool. 10 million lines might not give the best responsiveness, but give it a try.